# Exception caught during firing event net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent$Register@6b4d0be2: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

```
//import
@EventBusSubscriber
public class RegistryHandler {
@SubscribeEvent
public static void onItemRegister(RegistryEvent.Register<Item> event) {
    event.getRegistry().registerAll(ItemInit.ITEMS.toArray(new Item[0]));
    
}
@SubscribeEvent
public static  void onBlockRegister(RegistryEvent.Register<Block> event) {
    event.getRegistry().registerAll((Block[]) BlockInit.BLOCKS.toArray());
    
}
public static void onModelRegister(ModelRegistryEvent event) {
    for (Item item : ItemInit.ITEMS) {
        if (item instanceof IHasModel) {
            ((IHasModel)item).registerModels();
        }
    }
    for (Block block : BlockInit.BLOCKS) {
        if (block instanceof IHasModel) {
            ((IHasModel)block).registerModels();
        }
    }
}
```

}
So, i followed Harry Talks tutorials and tried to build the mod. It doesn't work for some unknown reason.
[Error Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qkncad6ylclj6b/debug.log?dl=0)
[Project code on github](https://github.com/path-converter/Compressor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the important part of your error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to set registry name with existing registry name! New: fur:decrafting_table Old: fur:decrafting_table
    at net.minecraftforge.registries.IForgeRegistryEntry$Impl.setRegistryName(IForgeRegistryEntry.java:71)
    at net.minecraftforge.registries.IForgeRegistryEntry$Impl.setRegistryName(IForgeRegistryEntry.java:79)
    at com.furnacelztmod.blocks.BlockBase.<init>(BlockBase.java:23)
```

The problem is here:

```
public BlockBase(String name, Material material) {
    super(material);
    setUnlocalizedName(name);
    setRegistryName(name);
    setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.BUILDING_BLOCKS);
    
    BlockInit.BLOCKS.add(this);
    Block iter=this;
    iter.setRegistryName(iter.getRegistryName()); // line 23
    ItemInit.ITEMS.add(new ItemBlock(iter));
}
```

Specifically, you shouldn't be doing `iter.setRegistryName(iter.getRegistryName());`. Forge doesn't let you do that, and even if it did, it would be a no-op, just setting the registry name to what it already was. I suspect you actually meant to set the registry name on the `ItemBlock` there, which you should be able to do by replacing the last three lines of that constructor with this:

```
ItemBlock iter=new ItemBlock(this);
iter.setRegistryName(this.getRegistryName());
ItemInit.ITEMS.add(iter);
```

Comment: yes, i wanted to set the registry name for the ItemBlock, but i don't know how.